# The endomorphism ring is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit and $M$ be a $R$-module.

I want to show that the endomorphism ring $\text{End}_R(M)=\text{Hom}_R(M,M)$ of a simple $R$-module is a field.

$$$$

We have that $\text{End}_R(M)=\text{Hom}_R(M,M)=\{f:M\rightarrow M \mid f \ : \ R-\text{ homomorphism}\}$.

Could you give me some hints how we could show that the endomorphism ring is a field?

Comment: It is a division ring not a field since it is not always commutative. This is a consequence of the Schur's lemma

Comment: From Schur's lemma we have that $f$ is an isomorphism, right?

Answer (score 5):

Schur's lemma tells you that an endomorphism of $M$ is either zero or invertible. That means precisely that $\text{End}_R(M)$ is a division ring. If $R$ is noncommutative this is the most that you can say.

But in fact, because $R$ is commutative, the simple $R$-modules have the form $R/m$ where $m$ is a maximal ideal, and their endomorphism rings are again $R/m$ where $m$ is a maximal ideal, so they're in fact fields and not just division rings.

Comment: Could you explain to me  at the last part why the endomorphism rings of the simple $R$-modules are again $R/m$ ?

Comment: @Mary: there's a natural map from $R$ to $\text{End}(R/m)$ (we really need to use that $R$ is commutative here). Show that it's surjective, then compute its kernel.

Comment: Is the mapping defined by $r\mapsto f(r)$ ?

Comment: @Mary: sorry, I should be more precise; by "map" I mean "ring homomorphism." That map isn't obviously a ring homomorphism (although I think it turns out to be).

Comment: I got stuck right now... What do I have to do to show that $\text{End}_R(R/m)\cong R/m$ ?

Comment: @Mary: show, more generally, that if $I$ is any ideal, then any endomorphism of $R/I$ is given by multiplication by $r$ for some $r \in R$. This gives a surjective ring homomorphism $R \to \text{End}_R(R/I)$. Now try to show that the kernel of this map is $I$.

Comment: So do we consider the mapping $r\mapsto rf$ ?